# Pascal's Triangle answer in leetcode

Tags: python, lambda

I saw a answer about `Pascal's Triangle` in leetcode, https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/discuss/, but i really don't understand how author did that.

```
def generate(self, numRows):
        res = [[1]]
        for i in range(1, numRows):
            res += [map(lambda x, y: x+y, res[-1] + [0], [0] + res[-1])]
        return res[:numRows]
```

I don't quite understand the `map` part. Hope someone could help me.

Comment: You don't understand what `map` does? You don't understand how lambda functions work? Or you understand those but don't think it would produce Pascal's Triangle?

Comment: @khelwood i understand both `map` and `lambda`, but i don't know how it product `Pascal's Triangle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the explanation below the leetcode example on their page:

> explanation: Any row can be constructed using the offset sum of the previous row. Example:
>
> ```
>    1 3 3 1 0   
> +  0 1 3 3 1  
> =  1 4 6 4 1
> ```

`res` is a list of lists, each representing a row in the triangle. `res[-1] + [0]` takes the last element in `res` and adds 0 to it (for example, `[1]` turns to `[1, 0]`). Similarly, `[0] + res[-1]` adds 0 in the beginning (`[1]` turns to `[0, 1]`).

The `map` part just adds two rows created in lambda part, as in leetcode explanation. `res += [map(...)]` adds the result to `res`.

For example, `generate(4)` gives you `[[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1]]`.

It is very helpful to add prints to various unclear parts of a code to try to understand it better.

Here's a couple of useful links:

https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

https://brilliant.org/wiki/pascals-triangle/